# PHP & SQL Empty Output when Select username

Tags: php, sql, json, cpanel, mybb

I am making a very simple webservice, outputing the request as a json. Well, I have no idea how it is properly done, I simply followed the different google examples.

The problem is that the codes give a blank output if I select username in the SQL. Without the username in SQL, it output just fine, is really strange. I am not sure if this is some security features or the codes have issues. I've confirmed the SQL with username is working in phpadmim.

```
$token = "some simple token";
$headers = apache_request_headers();

if (isset($headers['Authorization']) && $headers['Authorization'] == $token)
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect(ip, user, pw, db) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $sql = "SELECT u.username as userid, f.fid4 as gw2id FROM mybb_users u, mybb_userfields f WHERE u.uid = f.ufid AND (additionalgroups = 8 OR usergroup = 4 OR usergroup = 9 OR usergroup = 3) ORDER BY f.fid4";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any rows when you execute the query in PHPmyadmin? Maybe you're just sending an empty array in json format.

Comment: did you notice that `SELECT u.username as userid`, you get `username` as `userid` is it right ?

Comment: Does it pass the `if()` ?

Comment: yes, the phpadmin output everything just fine. there were hundreds of rows. the "userid" is simply the header i set for json.

the problem is if I include "u.username" in the select statment, the php code will give a blank output. if i exclude the "u.username" and replace with anything else. the php code will work. is really strange and puzzling.

i tried it without the if, just the raw code.

Comment: what if you put an echo json_encode($row) inside the while loop. Do you get anything?

Comment: nope. is null. i tried a very simple SQL "SELECT username FROM mybb_users" and it is blank as well. I think it is some kind of security features. anyone has any idea?